# What is an optimal amount for protein intake?

Tags: supplements, health

What exactly is a *safe* limit for taking whey protein? Different websites recommend different amounts of protein intake. The most common one that I see is around 0.8g of protein for every kilograms of weight.

I went to an [online calculator](http://www.healthizen.com/health-tools/calculators-trackers/protein-calculator.aspx) for protein requirement and given my body specifications, the calculator recommends that I take 48grams of protein per day. I think my daily usual food can reach 48g of protein easily. In fact, I don't need whey protein to reach 48g of protein, if the calculator is right.

On the other hand, some websites recommend up to over 100g of protein, which is more than twice the recommended protein intake from the calculator!

I weigh about 100 pounds and stand at 5'4. I am a male and have a relatively small and thin body frame. Apart from my recent venture into the gym on some of the days to spend an hour lifting weights, my activity level is pretty sedentary.

I ask because I'm worry that I may either consume too much protein, which may *overwork* my  liver and kidneys, or consume too little protein, which is not most effective for my training in building up muscle size.

At this point, I am taking two scoops of whey protein on days after lifting weights. On other days that I don't lift weights, I take one scoop of whey protein.

So, again, what is a *safe gauge* for the amount of protein intake so that my body remains *healthy* and does not need to work extra to flush out the unnecessary proteins?

Comment: I am 26 yrs old this year.

Comment: Check out the answers to http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/792/21 While your title suggests that you're looking for these answers, your text suggests that you want to know how much is the maximum safe amount. Those are two different questions.

Answer (score 1):

*Safe*? I wouldn't exceed 2g protein per *pound* of bodyweight, but it depends on what your body actually *needs*. It sounds like you're relatively sedantary--even still, 48g seems low, something more like 60-80g would be closer to ranges I've seen suggested.

That same calculator suggested 90g of protein per day for me--I'm 185lb at 5'10", exercise 2-3 hours a day (various types), and IMO 90g while safe is substantially below what my body requires. Calculators I've tried range from 80g-160g, which basically means "meh, we're making up numbers--if you really care, see a nutrutionist."

Answer (score 1):

There are studies that show that intakes up to 2.8g/kg are about fine [link](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10722779)

Some athletes have been taking way bigger amounts for decades and I'm yet to see a case of kidney damage under normal circumstances (no performance drugs).

If you do weightlifting and you're not in a massive caloric deficit, I think you'll do great with a range between 1.8 and 2g per kg.

1 kg = 2.2 pounds