# Why do bodybuilders need so much protein when 70 % of muscle is water?

Tags: bodybuilding, nutrition, protein

70 % of muscle is water.  Less than 30 % is protein.  10 kg (22 pounds) of muscle contain less than 3000 g protein.  It takes several months to build that much muscle.

That is bodybuilders need 3000g extra protein per few months which is not that big.

Comment: 3000g not 300g.

Comment: @JohnPietrar: Sorry, corrected.

Comment: Also, 30% of muscle is not "protein", it is is various structures within the fibers  and cells that *use* protein for building  and repair.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned less than

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already [some answers that address this](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/792/protein-how-much-is-too-much?rq=1), basically tissue is being torn down and needs to be repaired. But it goes further: [there are simply a pile of benefits to upping protein](http://advances.nutrition.org/content/3/3/322.full) (2012 study):

> Protein seems to play an important role in the emergence of [feeling full].
>   Long-term ingestion of a high-protein diet not only decreases food
>   intake but also lowers animals’ body weight and reduces body [fat deposits]
>   in animals and humans.

Just at a baseline (no strength training involved), [a 170lb man would need 61.2 grams of protein according to the US RDA](http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/how-much-protein-do-you-need-every-day-201506188096). So bumping that up to the generally accepted "1 gram of protein per pound of bodyweight" is a 110 gram bump from the baseline.

Beyond the gram-for-gram measurements, there's a lot going on about availability ([2005 review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15798080)):

> The response of muscle protein metabolism to a resistance exercise
>   bout lasts for 24-48 hours; thus, the interaction between protein
>   metabolism and any meals consumed in this period will determine the
>   impact of the diet on muscle hypertrophy. **Amino acid availability is
>   an important regulator of muscle protein metabolism**.

Boiled down, there are three reasons for the protein recommendations:

**1) Muscle Repair.** You are [destroying muscle tissue when you do resistance exercises](https://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/musclesgrowLK.html), and your body needs building materials (protein) repair that damage:

> Resistance training leads to trauma or injury of the cellular proteins
>   in muscle. This prompts cell-signaling messages to activate satellite
>   cells to begin a cascade of events leading to muscle repair and
>   growth.

**2) Carbohydrates.** There is a lot going on with carbohydrates and although your body needs them, they [tend to make up too much of a western diet and need interfere with muscle growth via insulin response, and promote fat storage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin#Physiological_effects). If you have a 2,500 calorie full of carbs and you increase your protein, chances are you'll be opting for chicken instead of bread.

**3) Availability.** Muscle repair can take dozens of hours to complete, during which the easy access to amino acids promotes tissue repair and regeneration.