# Can missed protein intake be compensated for?

Tags: nutrition, protein

I'm a 6'2 200lb male with and intense workout routine. Therfore, I aim to eat at about 180g protein a day. What I'm wondering is, if I miss my target one day, can I make up for it the next. E.g. if I anly consumed 140g on day 1, could I then costume 220g on day to to average 180g over the 2 days? I understand that it would not be as optimal as consuming 180g of protein evenly across 2 days but would be more beneficial than just consuming the usual 180g on day 2 and therfore averaging less than my protein goal across the 2 days?

Comment: David's answer is spot on. Also, you may be overconsuming - See the sports science reference [in this excellent answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/792/protein-how-much-is-too-much), even at the extreme end of need you really only need 160ish grams a day at 200 lbs (90..9 kg) Anything more is excreted, or potentially stored as fat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty confident that there's no scientific data available on that whatsoever.

That said, my guess would be that eating 220g of protein instead of 180g on the second day would not result in any improvement. Your aim in eating 180g of protein per day is to maximise muscle protein synthesis. If you haven't achieved that on day one, obviously you can't go beyond maximum muscle protein  synthesis on day two to compensate, since that would necessitate you exceeding your body's maximum possible rate of muscle protein synthesis.

Even within a day, working out in the morning, fasting for half the day, and then eating 180g of protein all in the evening is likely to be significantly inferior to distributing that protein more evenly across the day.